Pyomo.dae: handling events (rootfinding)
I have a DAE model of reasonable size (around 20 states) running quite well under Matlab. It relies heavily on events (rootfinding) that stop the integration, requires a computation of new starting point (based on previous values) and start over the integration.
Since the idea is to use the model for simulation, parameter estimation and possibly optimal control, I considered using Pyomo and its extension pyomo.dae. Docs indicate that the only DAE solver available is IDAS, through the use of CasADi.
My question: How do I implement my events? I could not find an example of a model using events in Pyomo, CasADi ou even Sundials docs (with Python :) ).
I did not try anything within Python (using MAtlab, it works well with ode15s, odeextend and the rootfinding (events) mechanism of matlab....)
Thank you, any help is welcome :)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
